# Two 50% divs with white-space:nowrap elements inside a flex container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to have a parent div that holds two 50% width children divs that resize with content.

One of them has an `h3` with `white-space:nowrap;` and this causes the div to grow past 50%.

I can force the div to return to 50% width using `min-width:0;` but the `h3` now overflows.

So I either get a different width on the child divs or an overflow from the h3 inside one of them.

Is it possible to make them have the same 50% width even with elements that have `white-space:nowrap;` inside?

Check out the problem here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VjPwLm?editors=1100

```css
#parent {
  background: whitesmoke;
  display: inline-flex;
}
#left {
  background: rgba(10, 200, 250, 0.5);
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
#right {
  background: rgba(250, 200, 10, 0.5);
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  /*min-width:0;*/
  /* Turn this on to see the h3 overflow */
}
h3 {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="left">Captain Deadpool</div>
  <div id="right">
    <h3>Very long title that does not entirelly fit into the div</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

If I understand correctly, you want the left flex item to be as wide as the long title.

Then, you can:

- Use `min-width: 100%` on both flex items to make them as wide as the concatenation of their texts. Then, they will be equally wide.
- But they are too wide, because the text of the first flex item is included. Use `width: 0` to ignore it.

```css
#parent {
  background: whitesmoke;
  display: inline-flex;
}
#left, #right {
  min-width: 100%;
}
#left {
  background: rgba(10,200,250,0.5);
  width: 0;
}
#right {
  background: rgba(250,200,10,0.5);
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="left">Captain Deadpool</div>
  <div id="right"><h3>Very long title that does not entirelly fit into the div</h3></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Smart. A side effect of using `width:0;` on the left flex item is that the background color and border of the flex container now only has 50% of it's correct width. Is there any way to correct for that?

Comment: @Amoguai Good point. I guess you could use `min-width: 50%` on the flex items, `width: 200%` on the flex container, and wrap it inside an inline-level container. [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/610o1whg/). But now the flex container will overflow the wrapper. I can't think any way to get rid of the overflow.

Comment: @Amoguai I have done it with a margin-right. But it breaks when the screen is too narrow, because it should be sized using max-content instead of the default fit-content. But not all browsers support `width: max-content`. [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/610o1whg/1/)

Comment: Using margins feels like a hack. Could it be that there's just no support for this in CSS (without using rules that aren't meant to be used like this)?

Comment: @Amoguai Yes, CSS was not designed to be able to size some elements relatively to the contents of other elements.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the issue properly, you want to maintian the 2 divs so that they have a 50% width.
Set the parent div to have a 100% width and then set the #right and #left to min-width: 50%;
Add to the h3 so that the overflow is hidden.

```css
#parent {
  background: whitesmoke;
  display: inline-flex;
}
#left {
  background: rgba(10, 200, 250, 0.5);
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-width: 100%;
}
#right {
  background: rgba(250, 200, 10, 0.5);
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-width: 100%;
}
h3 {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="left">Captain Deadpool</div>
  <div id="right">
    <h3>Very long title that does not entirelly fit into the div</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want the parent and child divs to resize with their content instead of overflowing. Basically I want the parent div to have twice the width of the biggest child div.

Comment: It's not very important because I can use media queries to reformat the behavior on small screens, but ideally they would stack like floating elements.